# The maximum cores a CPU will contains?

Tags: cpu

I've just read the news, a 100-core CPU was released. Though the news is two years ago.

[image]

*I'm wondering whether the size of the 100-core CPU is more or less just the same as Intel CPUs.*

The nano-wire is already so small, as the Moore's Law seems to be dead in foreseeable future,   the size of a core will be reach a limit then, how can too many cores built into one chip?

Comment: [I read it was up to 1000.](http://www.gla.ac.uk/news/headline_183814_en.html)

Comment: *The possibilities are endless...* / *Nothing is impossible...*

Comment: 100-core CPUs are neat and all, but how is this related to system administration?  Your question is probably more appropriate on a electronics or chip manufacturing forum.

Comment: As interesting as this is, this is off topic.

Comment: Over 9000, of course.

Comment: Think outside the box SilverbackNet, its an octillion silly.

Comment: "If you were plowing a field, which would you rather use: Two strong oxen or 1024 chickens?" -- Seymour Cray

Comment: Voting to close because this is absolutely impossible to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moore's Law is far from dead. Read up on **semiconductor device fabrication**. We are only at 32nm right now, and the road map has already been laid for 22nm, 16nm, and 11nm. Moore's Law will not die until the PNP or NPN of a transistor are each one atom thick... and it may not even die then (if we can learn to manipulate quarks that is).

With that said we can expect to see as many cores on a processor as will fit in die space `x` given manufacturing process `y`. Hundreds of cores will probably be mainstream in the very near future, and thousands may be on the horizon as well.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the transistors in modern CPUs use gates, not junctions. Your point does stand though.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Yeah, I just didn't want to make the subject too cloudy :)

Comment: I've been told by an AMD engineer that the scales we are at are starting to see quantum effects such as electron tunneling that is limiting how small you can go. The solution has been, as you have seen, to scale out (rather than down) with multiple cores.

Comment: Nothing like clouding the subject with correct terminology...;->

Comment: @Keith  I've read something like that in some of the IEEE's publications. I'll try to dig up some references later.

Comment: I think saying "FAR FROM DEAD" isn't being realistic.  32nm to 11nm is just 3 generations, @ 3 years for a generation to keep w/ Moore's law that is only a decade. A single silicon atom is 0.2nm across and even perfectly constructed a NAND gate requires 5 atoms (~1nm).Below 5nm is unlikely due to quantum effects. 

One way to look at is is realizing we went from 1500nm (286 CPU in 1978) to 32nm (Core I-7in 2011).  If we consider the size of a silicon gate @ 1nm as the absolute limit and 5nm as a realistic limit we are much closer to the finish line than the beginning.

Comment: @theUnhandledException 500 years ago we thought the Earth was flat. Less than 100 years ago the atom was only conjecture. It is hubris to say that we have reach the limit of anything. What if they find some way to make transistors on the quark level instead of the atomic level? With all we have discovered isn't it logical to assume that there are particles even smaller than a quark that we just cannot detect yet? Everything is made of something, and we always seem to find a way to manipulate that "something". As long as we can do that Moore's law will live on and technology will progress.

Comment: Moore's law states that processor density will double every 18 months not just get faster "eventually".  To avoid breaking Moore's  we will need 11nm processing within 5 years, 5nm (limit theorized by Intel who knows a little about silicon fabrication) within 7 years, and 1nm (limit of atomic based silicon gates) within a decade.  So while humans may indeed have much faster non-silicon computers **someday** that doesn't mean Moore's law will remain intact; unless your quark computer arrives in next 10 years Moore's law will fail as we hit atomic limits of silicon.

Comment: @theUnhandledException I'll post back in 10 years :)

Comment: @typoking  That's worth a +1.  :)

Comment: Oh really... * Somehow * it's all going to work out fine right?

Comment: @ubiquibacon You didn’t post back. You’re two years overdue.

Comment: @Константин Ван Not in base 16.

Answer (score 2):

If I write a number from my imagination or if I find and cite a research paper and someone reads this 10 years from now, he will probably laugh at bad predictions.

So I'll just say that the number will be limited by [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) and specific needs of target market.

A bit of clarification on the needs part: To put it simply, compare today's GPUs and CPUs. GPUs have large number of relatively limited cores, which is OK for graphics processing, while each CPU core can do much more complex operations.

Comment: Agreed. See the link for the 1000-core processor in one of the comments, it's effectively a hardware MPEG-decoder. We may well end up with a very large number of very simple cores